# Convert File To Another File By Shell Script

Tags: shell, unix

I want to convert below input file(abc) to output file(xyz) as mentioned below:

```
$more abc
"2005057400BPI","TS.1.BPI.20121112120000.000#S10S#.txt.xml"
"2005057408BPI","TS.1.BPI.20121112120000.000#S10S#.txt.xml"
"2005057488BPI","TS.1.BPI.20121112120000.000#S10S#.txt.xml"

$more xyz
"2005057400BPI",TS.1.BPI.20121112120000.000.txt
"2005057408BPI",TS.1.BPI.20121112120000.000.txt
"2005057488BPI",TS.1.BPI.20121112120000.000.txt
```

File abc contains aorund 35k lines. I am doing conversion as:

```
$perl -pi -e 's/"//g' abc
$cut -d'.' -f1-5 abc > xyz
$perl -pi -e 's/.....$/\.txt/g' xyz
$perl -pi -e 's/#//g' xyz

$perl -pi -e 's/^/"/g' xyz
$perl -pi -e 's/,/",/g' xyz
```

Is there any other way to do it faster with less number of commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Perl:

```
perl -plne 's/#.*/.txt/;s/,"/,/;'  file
```

Add option -i to update the file in place.

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
sed 's/"\(TS.*\)#S10S#.txt.xml"/\1.txt/' input
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(.*,\)"\([^#]*\).*/\1\2.txt/' file
```

Results:

```
"2005057400BPI",TS.1.BPI.20121112120000.000.txt
"2005057408BPI",TS.1.BPI.20121112120000.000.txt
"2005057488BPI",TS.1.BPI.20121112120000.000.txt
```

Comment: `sed` also comes with in-place capabilities, with the `-i` flag. However, not all `sed`'s were made equal. So see your versions man page.